# Entity Framework esta salvando valores duplicados quando salvo entidades com relacionamento N para N

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho uma entidade chamada Livro que possui entre outros atributos uma lista de categorias. No meu modelo um livro pode ter múltiplas categorias e vice versa, logo temos um relacionamento N para N. O EF cria portanto a tabela livros, a tabela categoria e uma de associação entre elas.

Para criar um novo livro no banco de dados eu instancio um objeto do tipo Livro, populo os atributos e para cada categoria selecionada no formulário eu adiciono um novo objeto do tipo categoria a lista de categorias do objeto livro apenas populando o Id da Categoria.

```
 novoLivro.Categorias.Add(new Categoria(){CategoriaId = selectedId})
```

Adiciono o objeto livro ao meu DbContext e ele salva o livro corretamente no banco de dados.

Porém, ele salva novos registros na tabela categoria, o que não deveria, afinal todas as minhas categorias já estão no banco e os objetos tem ate os id.

Como fazer para o EF entender que deveria somente salvar o novo livro, as associações e não salvar as categorias na tabela de categoria como se fossem novos registros?

Comment: Valeu galera. As duas respostas resolvem meu problema. A ideia do Attach eh interessante porque nao vou ao banco de dados so para recuperar algo que ja tinha ido anteriormente. Se eu tiver 20 categorias, eu teria que fazer 20 selects quando executasse o find.

Comment: Tranquilaço. Se quiser dar um upvote além do accept pra me dar uma força, eu agradeço!

Comment: Opa, certamente. Mas parece que preciso de mais reputação para fazer isso, assim que eu obtiver , eu volto aqui e dou um upvote. Valeu!

Comment: Veja agora. Com 10 de reputação você consegue.

Comment: precisa de 15 pontos :/

Comment: Agora sim. Upvoted. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque o contexto intui que você está criando um novo objeto. Se você não precisa carregar as categorias, você pode usar objetos ocos anexados ao contexto apenas para salvar a nova entidade, mais ou menos assim:

```cs
var categoria = new Categoria { CategoriaId = selectedId };
context.Categorias.Attach(categoria);
novoLivro.Categorias.Add(categoria);
```

Caso você faça questão de carregar o registro da categoria, utilize a solução do @JBruni.

Answer (score 2):

Você está criando uma nova categoria com `new Categoria`.

Você precisa passar o objeto da Categoria já existente como parâmetro:

```
novoLivro.Categorias.Add(categoriasContext.Categorias.Find(selectedId))
```